# Android writing to CSV RAM issue

Tags: java, android, csv, android-sqlite, android-external-storage

I'm collecting a bunch of sensor data in a Service, storing it into a SQL table, and when the user clicks a button I take all of that SQL data and save it to a CSV file, but I keep getting `Window is full: requested allocation XXX` errors showing in logcat

From a bit of googling I think this might be due to high RAM usage on my Nexus 5x?

When the user clicks the save button, the code to begin the process looks like this:

```
File subjectFile = new File(subjectDataDir, subNum + ".csv");

try{
    dbHelper.exportSubjectData(subjectFile, subNum);
} catch (SQLException | IOException e){
    mainActivity.logger.e(getActivity(), TAG, "exportSubjectData error", e);
}
```

Then in my DBHelper, the `exportSubjectData` method looks like this:

```
public void exportSubjectData(File outputFile, String subNum) throws IOException, SQLException {

    csvWrite = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile));

    curCSV = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DATA_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE id = " + subNum, null);

    csvWrite.writeNext(curCSV.getColumnNames());

    while (curCSV.moveToNext()) {

        String arrStr[] = {curCSV.getString(0), curCSV.getString(1), curCSV.getString(2),
                curCSV.getString(3), curCSV.getString(4), curCSV.getString(5),
                curCSV.getString(6), curCSV.getString(7), curCSV.getString(8),
                curCSV.getString(9), curCSV.getString(10)};

        csvWrite.writeNext(arrStr);
    }

    csvWrite.close();
    curCSV.close();
}
```

Firstly, is this type of problem normally caused by RAM usage?

Assuming that my problem is high RAM usage in that section of code, is there a more efficient way to do this without consuming so much memory? The table that its trying to write to CSV has over 300,000 rows and 10 columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are using opencsv. What you can try is calling `csvWrite.flush()` after every x calls of `csvWrite.writeNext(arrStr)`. That should write the data from memory to the disc.
You have to try what the best value for x is.